# POST Entity to Fiware-Orion with Java

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm trying to create a new Entity in Orion using the example from the fiware-orion cookbook
(http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/cookbook/), by executing this code:

```
   @RequestMapping("/postest")
   public void viewTest() throws Exception{
      Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
      Entity payload = Entity.json("{'id':'Room13','type':'Room'}");

      Response response = client.target("http://my-url:1026/v2/entities")
      .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
      .post(payload);

      System.out.println("status: " + response.getStatus());
      System.out.println("headers: " + response.getHeaders());
      System.out.println("body:" + response.readEntity(String.class));

   }
```

but as a result I get this error: "error":"ParseError","description":"Errors found in incoming JSON buffer"

On the other hand, the GET example works fine. Is something not working as it is described or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orion returns `ParseError` whenever it receives a request which JSON payload has some kind of syntax error. Thus, I'd recommend you to ensure the JSON you are sending from your program is ok. There are several ways of doing this:

1. Log traces in your code (you are using Java, so a `println` in the right place with the right parameters wouldd do the trick).
2. Replace the CB endpoint by some mock able to show the received requests, e.g. `nc` command or tools like [PutsReq](http://putsreq.com/).
3. Capture it on the wire, using tools like tcpdump or wireshark.

Looking to your code I see `{'id':'Room13','type':'Room'}`. Maybe the problem is that your are using `'` instead of `"` (check [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/)).

Comment: Ok, that was a rookie mistake, being affected by php's " and ' equality didn't even think about it.. Changing the payload to `"{\"id\":\"Room13\",\"type\":\"Room\"}"` fixed the problem. Thank you!